# group_by and reduce of Enumerable not playing well together

Tags: ruby

I am reading a csv file. One of headers of csv is called case. Some rows will have the same case. And I want to group them together. I also want to use reduce on the collection in order to pass data into a new array:

```
csv = CSV.parse(file, :headers => true)
csv.group_by { |i| i[2] }.reduce([]) do |(key,collection),acc|
  attrs = []
  attrs << collection[0]

  ...

  acc << attrs
end
```

I expect key to be something like 18CA, which is a case number. And i expect collection to be an array of all the rows with that case number. And I expect acc to start as an empty array and grow with data through each iteration. But instead key is nil and collection is nil and acc is the current iteration of the group_by result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably `file` is a file name but that's not what `CSV.parse` expects as its first argument: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block parameters to [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) are just backwards the accumulator is the first parameter passed to the block, with the enumerable element being second.

```
csv.group_by { |i| i[2] }.reduce([]) do |acc, (key,collection)|
```

The reason `key` and `collection` were `nil` was being you were destructuring your accumulator value which starts as an empty array, essentially:

```
key, collection = []
key # => nil
collection # => nil
```